# Binned Bar chart using SAS

Tags: sas, data-visualization

I'm trying to make a bar chart using SAS. I have multiple salaries data and I'd like to show a bar chart with the frequencies of these salaries. I've made this:

```
ODS GRAPHICS ON;
PROC FREQ DATA=WORKERS.SORT ORDER=INTERNAL;
    TABLES salaries / NOCUM  SCORES=TABLE plots(only)=freq;
RUN;
ODS GRAPHICS OFF;
```

It works, the problem is, that now I can see all (hundreds) of the salaries on the x-axis. I'd like to have just intervals of these salaries (like 20) so that I can get a more readable chart. I just can't find out how to do it. I've also tried it with this:

```
PROC CHART DATA=WORK.SORT;
    vbar salaries;
RUN;
```

but that's a text representation of the chart, so I can't use it.

Comment: FYI, `PROC GCHART` or `PROC SGPLOT` are the graphical-chart procs.  `PROC CHART` is for text (ASCII graphics) charts.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a format and apply the format to the variable you want to group into buckets.  Here's an example:

```
proc format ;
  value myfmt
  low - 13 = '13 and Under'
  14 - high = '14 and Above';
run;


ODS GRAPHICS ON;
PROC FREQ DATA=sashelp.class ORDER=INTERNAL;
    format age myfmt.;
    TABLES age / NOCUM  SCORES=TABLE plots(only)=freq;
RUN;
ODS GRAPHICS OFF;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use PROC UNIVARIATE with the HISTOGRAM statement.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/66703/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_toc.htm

```
ods html;
proc univariate data=sashelp.cars noprint;
var msrp;
histogram;
run;
```

There are options for specifying bin size:

```
ods html;
proc univariate data=sashelp.cars noprint;
var msrp;
histogram / midpoints=30000 to 180000 by 30000;
run;
```

Comment: I think this is the best route.  What you're asking for is a histogram (a binned bar chart showing the distribution of continuous or semicontinuous data), so make a histogram (either in `PROC UNIVARIATE` or in `PROC SGPLOT` or similar).  `PROC FREQ` also works as Rob notes, but this is more precise for what you are really asking for; only use `PROC FREQ` if it gives you some advantage (like a better default format for your needs).

Comment: Nice.  I like this better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

And just for completeness, I'll add another solution in case you want more control over the chart's appearance.  Using the Graphics Template Language you can create some very nice looking charts.

The `proc template` statement defines how the chart will look.  The `sgrender` runs the chart against the specified dataset.  There's all kinds of options that are best explored in the online doc: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatgraph/65377/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1sxw5gidyzrygn1ibkzfmc5c93m.htm

I've just taken the sample they provided and added the `/ nbins=20` option to have it automatically group into 20 bins.  It also has options for start and end bin, bin size, etc..

```
proc template;
  define statgraph histogram;
    begingraph;
      entrytitle "Histogram of Vehicle Weights";
      layout overlay /
        xaxisopts=(label="Vehicle Weight (LBS)")
        yaxisopts=(griddisplay=on);
        histogram weight / nbins=20;
      endlayout;       
    endgraph;
  end;
run;

proc sgrender data=sashelp.cars template=histogram;
run;
```